# Serverless Framework function HTTP trigger event configuration

Tags: refactoring, yaml, serverless-framework

Say I have a serverless app that uses multiple Lambda functions triggered by HTTP event, where they all follow a similar URL format (same path parameter) - for example:
Function 1 path is: `events/{id}`
Function 2 path is: `events/{id}/attendees`
Function 3 path is: `events/{id}/join`

My `serverless.yml` is starting to look like:

```
...
functions:
  get_event:
    handler: handler.getEvent
    events:
      - http:
        path: events/{id}
        method: get
        cors: true
        request:
          parameters:
            paths:
              id: true
  get_event_attendees:
    handler: handler.getEventAttendees
    events:
      - http:
        path: events/{id}/attendees
        method: get
        cors: true
        request:
          parameters:
            paths:
              id: true
  join_event:
    handler: handler.joinEvent
    events:
      - http:
        path: events/{id}/join
        method: post
        cors: true
        request:
          parameters:
            paths:
              id: true
```

What is a good way to refactor these http event declarations to reduce the redundancy?

I'm aware of the [serverless variables](https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/variables/) syntax, but unsure of how I can make something more like a function, that accepts as arguments the different path parameters, and returns the appropriate YML.

I believe doing something like:

```
custom:
  httpRequest:
    parameters:
      paths:
        id: true

...

functions:
  get_event:
    handler: handler.getEvent
    events:
      - http:
        path: events/{id}
        method: get
        request: ${self:custom:httpRequest}
  get_event_attendees:
    handler: handler.getEventAttendees
    events:
      - http:
        path: events/{id}/attendees
        method: get
        request: ${self:custom:httpRequest}
  ...
```

only works if all the HTTP functions I ever write only have that one path parameter `id`.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I wouldn't worry about it. There is some level of verbosity needed because of the sheer number of elements that can be configured but the redundancy in no way negatively affects the performance of your application. And while it may seem redundant, what you really have is the granularity to affect change very uniquely across your functions as well as the clarity to see what the differences are between them.

If you want to clean up the serverless.yml overall look at breaking out into separate files perhaps for all the function definitions or perhaps per event https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/variables/#reference-variables-in-other-files

That will probably server you better by keeping related entities together but segregated so there's less cognitive load when looking at the base serverless.yml file.